# JQuery autocomplete: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using [this jquery autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) plugin. But when I search click on a filtered result i get this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined**

Here is the stacktrace from the inspector console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
Autocomplete.onSelect @ jquery.autocomplete.min.js:915
Autocomplete.select @ jquery.autocomplete.min.js:850
(anonymous function) @ jquery.autocomplete.min.js:195
n.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Here is the method I call:

```
var url = $(item).data('url');
var keyField = $(item).data('keyField') !== undefined ? $(item).data('keyField') : 'id';
var valueField = $(item).data('valueField') !== undefined ? $(item).data('valueField') : 'description';

$(myItem).devbridgeAutocomplete({
    serviceUrl: myUrl,
    minChars: 0,
    type: 'post',
    deferRequestBy: 500,
    transformResult: function (response) {
        var json_response = $.parseJSON(response);

        var suggestions = $.map(json_response.items, function (dataItem) {
                var interface = $('.content-wrapper').interface();

                return {value: dataItem[valueField], data: dataItem[keyField]};
            });

        return {suggestions: suggestions};
    },
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        // Do my stuff to populate the view
    }
});
```

Looking at the source code, the problem raises when the function `onSelect()` is called because no suggestions are in the array.

Why that array is empty? I'm selecting a filtered value so should have one element

Comment: `devbridgeAutocomplete` ??

Comment: @jai https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete#known-issues

Comment: I couldn't find where your `valueField` and `keyField` are defined.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry... These two values are a `data-value-field` an `data-key-field` on the input. Since I have many autocomplete, I use these two fields in order to know what kind of response is returned... For example if I return a response with ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION in the first autocomplete I want ID and NAME and in the second I want ID and DESCRIPTION in this case what i look for is ID and Description

Comment: Can you post `console.log(json_response);` output here? That might be helpful

Comment: I've found a solution as described in my answer, thanks anyway!

Comment: strange SO didn't load that automatically. Good to know you got your issue resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution for the problem:

Here is the [issue](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/issues/440) I've opened on GitHub. The problem was on the `onSelect()` function.

> I refer to the version **1.2.24**
>
> ```
> onSelect: function (index) {
>         var that = this,
>             onSelectCallback = that.options.onSelect,
>             suggestion = that.suggestions[index];
>
>         that.currentValue = that.getValue(suggestion.value);
>
>         if (that.currentValue !== that.el.val() && !that.options.preserveInput) {
>             that.el.val(that.currentValue);
>         }
>
>         that.signalHint(null);
>         that.suggestions = [];
>         that.selection = suggestion;
>
>         if ($.isFunction(onSelectCallback)) {
>             onSelectCallback.call(that.element, suggestion);
>         }
>     },
> ```
>
> I've changed the method to:
>
> ```
> onSelect: function (index) {
>     var that = this,
>             onSelectCallback = that.options.onSelect,
>             suggestion = that.suggestions.length >= 1 ? that.suggestions[index] : that.suggestions;
>
>     that.currentValue = that.getValue(suggestion.value);
>
>     if (that.currentValue !== that.el.val() && !that.options.preserveInput) {
>         that.el.val(that.currentValue);
>     }
>
>     that.signalHint(null);
>     that.suggestions = [];
>     that.selection = suggestion;
>
>     if ($.isFunction(onSelectCallback)) {
>         onSelectCallback.call(that.element, suggestion);
>     }
> },
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I added check before accessing value:
label = ui.item.attr( "aria-label" ) || (item?item.value:'');